# JQuery ajax(), or load() return incomplete response in IE. Works fine in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

When using JQuery's **asynchronous** method to **GET** a remote URL through either `ajax()` or `load()`, the returned response is corrupted in IE but completely correct in Chrome.

Here is the sample code

```
    $('#contactEmailPanelBody .panel-body').load('contact/email/list/' + id, function(response, status, xhr) {
        console.log('status=' + status);
        console.log('head=' + xhr.getResponseHeader('contentType'));
        console.log('response=' + response);

    });
```

The response is incomplete and corrupted when using IE/11.  But the complete correct document was successfully returned when using Chrome.

I've done a lot research and seems this is not caused by cache.  It seems some weird behavior of IE.

Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: IE is legend! It's like Windows 95 vs Windows 10 Anniversary Edition.xD

Answer (score 0):

I think of 2 possible reasons:

1. The first is that in internet explorer asks you permission to run scripts that run on files inside your pc, the best thing would be to try upload them to the server and test them from the server, maybe there if the function works well,
2. The second is to check the compatibility of browsers with the version of jquery you are using, you can do it at: http://jquery.com/browser-support/, you may have to put some patch compatibility for the browser you are Using.

Comment: Thanks, @Ajvillalon.  *Firstly*, the target was on server and it is not local resource.  Also, chrome has proved the response is being returned from **server** completely.  *Secondly*, I'm using JQuery 1.11.1 and IE/11.